# Vaadin's Binder#hasChanges() returns falsely 'false'

Tags: data-binding, vaadin8

I'm using the `binder.addStatusChangeListener( ... )` part of the code at [Binding  Data to Forms, Checking a return value](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html) in my webapp. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) derived from that is:

#### Person Bean

```java
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    public Person() {}

    public Person( final String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName( final String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

#### Person View

```java
public class PersonView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final Person person = new Person( "Gerold Broser" );
    private final TextField name = new TextField( "Name:" );
    private final BeanValidationBinder<Person> binder =
            new BeanValidationBinder<>( Person.class );
    private final Button button = new Button( "Button" );

    public PersonView() {
        super();

        binder.bindInstanceFields( this );
        binder.setBean( person );

        addComponent( name );
        addComponent( button );

        binder.addStatusChangeListener( event -> {
            final boolean hasChanges, isValid;
            out.println( "hasChanges=" + (hasChanges = event.getBinder().hasChanges()) );
            out.println( "isValid=" + (isValid = event.getBinder().isValid()) );
            button.setEnabled( hasChanges && isValid );
        } );
    }
}
```

As soon as I change the `TextField`'s content in my browser I get the following output:

```
hasChanges=false
isValid=true
```

Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [javadoc](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.5/com/vaadin/data/Binder.html#hasChanges--):

> `public boolean hasChanges()`
>
> Check whether any of the bound fields' have uncommitted changes since last explicit call to `readBean(Object)`, `removeBean()`, `writeBean(Object)` or 
>    `writeBeanIfValid(Object)`. Unsuccessful writeoperations will not affect this value.
>
> **Note that if you use `setBean(Object)` method, Binder tries to commit changes as soon as all validators have passed. Thus, when using
>   this method with it seldom makes sense and almost always returns
>   false.**
>
> Return values for each case are compiled into the following
>   table:

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦══════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║            ║ After      ║ After   ║ After   ║ After successful ║ After unsuccessful ║
║            ║ readBean,  ║ valid   ║ invalid ║ writeBean or     ║ writeBean or       ║
║            ║ setBean or ║ user    ║ user    ║ writeBeanIfValid ║ writeBeanIfValid   ║
║            ║ removeBean ║ changes ║ changes ║                  ║                    ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ A bean is  ║            ║         ║         ║                  ║                    ║
║ currently  ║   false    ║  false  ║  true   ║      false       ║     no change      ║
║ bound      ║            ║         ║         ║                  ║                    ║
╟────────────╫────────────╫─────────╫─────────╫──────────────────╫────────────────────╢
║ No bean is ║            ║         ║         ║                  ║                    ║
║ currently  ║   false    ║  true   ║  true   ║      false       ║     no change      ║
║ bound      ║            ║         ║         ║                  ║                    ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩══════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

> `Returns:`
>   whether any bound field's value has changed since last call to setBean, readBean, writeBean or writeBeanIfValid

In conclusion, using `setBean(myBean)` will trigger automatic *commits*. Thus, if you want to [manually commit changes](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html#manual-reading-and-writing), use `binder.readBean(myBean)`& `binder.writeBean(myBean)`.